# After I used vue.js, why console.log() only can print function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I use `console.log()`  before importing `vue.js`, that is all fine.
However when I used `vue.js`, the action of `console.log` have been changed.
such as

```
{…}
__ob__: {…}
dep: {…}
id: 167
subs: Array [ {…} ]
__proto__: Object { addSub: addSub(), removeSub: removeSub(), depend: depend(), … }
value: {…}
__ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
__proto__: Object { … }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: click the dots to expand/get the value

Comment: that just expand object and can't see value but function

Comment: click the dots again, you have to invoke the function to get latest/actual value. See the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316) here, and the fix that explain why the console do that [here](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/125174/webkit). I'd say Vue and the like are "reactive", that's why.

Comment: Why dont you use Vue Developer Tools in console? There you have all data